# modules for building ajax application and friendly urls?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm building an ajax application using drupal 7, i found a module with some help ajax_nodeloader, but also i need load panel pages, views, etc.

Until now i'm overriding template theme file (zen) for ajax requests, and trying to use jquery address for good seo.

Also i will use jQuery UI Layout Plug-in on my template.

Which modules do you recommend ?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need an additional module, Drupal's [AJAX framework](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax/7) should provide the needed features. For instance, it [can easily be used to *ajaxify* links](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/drupal-code/make-link-use-ajax-drupal-7-its-easy).

See the [AJAX Example](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example!ajax_example.module/group/ajax_example/7), [AJAX Graceful Degradation](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example!ajax_example_graceful_degradation.inc/group/ajax_degradation_example/7) and [AJAX Commands](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example!ajax_example_advanced.inc/7) example modules for API usages.

Comment: and how to manage seo friendly ajax urls ? like http://lab.laukstein.com/ajax-seo/

Comment: For links, in you HTML you can have URLs with a `nojs` path element which will be replaced by `ajax` when used by the AJAX Framework.

Comment: how can i retrieve any path content (nodes, views, panels) on ajax callback, actually i'm using at theme level "if ajax request" print only content, i think i can have be a cleaner solution, thank you

Comment: IMHO, Ajaxifying the page is not a theme job. While it deals with presentation, it needs deeper collaboration with backend behaviors and should be done in a module. Handler functions for most paths are made to return full HTML page and are not really fitted to return partial content, and certainly not with theme only code. The https://drupal.org/project/ajax_regions may provide the wanted feature.

Comment: Excellent comments ! thank you i will make some tests

Comment: success using ajax regions example, now i have a page view with ajax links loading node content with ajax, but i cannot get working adress bar update, example: i'm on /nodes and after i click a node link i want to change it to /node/1 (html5) or /#!/node/1

Comment: as recommended here http://drupal.org/node/1271484 i implemented jquery address and also with ideas of ajax nodeloader i updated my code for updating title